# Font text not correctly rendered at big sizes on Retina Displays using Safari 6.0

Tags: css, fonts, safari, rendering, retina-display

I just started coding my own website, and since I love typographic web design I was trying to use a really big custom font for the logo. Unfortunately during my testing on Safari using a MacBook Pro with Retina displays I noticed that there were some artifacts in the font rendering :/ First I thought there was some mistake on my part, but then I discovered that it happens with any font if it is big enough...

This behavior is visible on websites like http://fittextjs.com where the outline of the title is not correctly rendered. For anyone without a retina display here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about http://cl.ly/JL0j

Odd enough this strange bug isn't present on Chrome, and since they're both Webkit based I thought that maybe the latter is using a CSS default that renders text correctly.

Any CSS guru that knows how to solve the situation before me filling a rdar :) ?

UPDATE: I should note that I already tried using -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; and it doesn't work :/

Comment: Is the screenshot from between T and e? Because if so, then there is another bug in Chrome on Windows 7 on the T, see [screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9714808/fittext_chrome.jpg). Therefor it probably is a render issue not depending on Retina or not.

Comment: Yeah, it is :/ It's strange because the osx version of chrome isn't affected, maybe they optimized the rendering when adding support for the retina display? I don't know, I should try to install win7 and try Chrome there to if it's affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filled a radar about it yesterday and got an answer today (never got a response so fast!).

Apple engineers are aware of it and consider it a serious bug, so I hope it'll get fixed soon. In the meantime there's no workaround available apart from using images :/